# jquery replacewith to get data with Ajax after click on a cell

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

am working on a code which I want to use as follow: 
there is a html table A and the user can click on the first cell of a row. 
The click causes a replacewith-function with jquery. From the cell the user had clicked before he got the id or a keyword for the search in the mysql database. For example the user clicks on an ID which is 1. Then the function would start searching for an entry with the same id.

I have a code already, but think there must be a mistake. Anybody here who can help?
By the way: if you don't really understand what I mean, don't hesitate to ask me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( "#mytable tr td:first-child" ).click(function() {
    $( "#yourtable" ).replaceWith( function showUser(str)
        {
            if (str=="")
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>


</head>
<title></title>


<body>


<table border="1" rules="groups" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Assoziation 1</th>
      <th>Assoziation 2</th>
      <th>Assoziation 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><i>betroffen:<br>4 Mio. Menschen</i></td>
      <td><i>betroffen:<br>2 Mio. Menschen</i></td>
      <td><i>betroffen:<br>1 Mio. Menschen</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Berlin</td>
      <td>Hamburg</td>
      <td>M&uuml;nchen</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Milj&ouml;h</td>
      <td>Kiez</td>
      <td>Bierdampf</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Buletten</td>
      <td>Frikadellen</td>
      <td>Fleischpflanzerl</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" rules="groups" id="yourtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Assoziation 1</th>
      <th>Assoziation 2</th>
      <th>Assoziation 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><i>betroffen:<br>4 Mio. Menschen</i></td>
      <td><i>betroffen:<br>2 Mio. Menschen</i></td>
      <td><i>betroffen:<br>1 Mio. Menschen</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Berlin</td>
      <td>Hamburg</td>
      <td>M&uuml;nchen</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Milj&ouml;h</td>
      <td>Kiez</td>
      <td>Bierdampf</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Buletten</td>
      <td>Frikadellen</td>
      <td>Fleischpflanzerl</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

getuser.php

```
 <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
//$q = 2;

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','boerse');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


$sql="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE share_id = '".$q."' GROUP BY time DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['usr_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['share_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ordertype'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**EDITED** **UPDATED**
Okay, I now changed some code lines. Generally I would say I get 'str'. But it doesn't work. I can see the table. But without the expected data output.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','boerse');
$sql="SELECT short, name FROM markets";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>




    <div class="markets">

<?
echo "<table>
<thead border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody border='1'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='nr'>".$row['short']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='information'>Use</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
<div class="clicked_info" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">Hello</div>  
    </div>
<br><br>

<div id="txtHint"><b>Info will be listed here.</b></div>


<script>

$(".information").click(function () {
  var str = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text(); //thank you David
  $.get("getuser_exp.php", {q:str}, function(data){ 
        $("#txtHint").replaceWith(data);

    });

}); 



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The getuser_exp.php is following:

```
 <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
//$q = 'SP500';

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','boerse');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


$sql="SELECT * FROM markets WHERE short = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>short</th>
<th>category</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['short'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Problem must be in the script, but why? I displayed 'var str' in a div. It was the right result.
I see that I have to learn much. I tried to find a good tutorial, but not what I am looking for to solve the problem.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: What is your problem? I can't tell from what you posted.

Comment: Sorry for this. My problem is that I don't get a result/no new html table.
I know that the AJAX-code is working because I tested before without the jquery for replacewith. So I think the reason why I don't get a result is a wrong gearing of jquery and AJAX.But what exactly? I can't find.

Comment: Your replaceWith inner function has no return, so you are not giving it a value to replaceWith.

Comment: Where are you getting the variable `str` from?

Comment: Okay, I updated the text and the code.

Comment: Try `$("#txtHint").load("getuser_exp.php", {q:str}, function(){ 
  //Call back function, do something if you want 
    });` instead of `$.get("getuser_exp.php", {q:str}, function(data){ 
        $("#txtHint").replaceWith(data);

    });`

Comment: @Satpal Thank you. Not yet solved. But the Problem will be that I have a problem to understand what I should insert into the last function.

Comment: @user3088932, As per my understanding of proplem. As you are getting `str`, thus event is getting fired(do a `alert`). replaceWith method replaces the selector so second time that you wont find any element.

Comment: @Satpal: Maybe the replacewith is the problem in the question. I want to use the content of the clicked cell to show all database-table entries with a similar value (e.g. ID). I worked with this example first: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp). But it doesn't work because I don't use select.
Imagine a table with car producers. I click on Tata with the ID XYZ and this XYZ is str. This click will result that the second div or txtHint show all cars produced by Tata in a table. Just an example. But this I like to do with tables, not select. Maybe it changes the way how to.

Comment: Problem was "intval" at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very odd. I assume your problem is coming from your Javascript/jQuery.

Your code is not using a callback function that I can see, so I would change your code to update after the XMLHTTPRequest is finished:

```
$( "#mytable tr td:first-child" ).click(function() {

    //I'm not sure where you are getting str from, but get it before you call this:

    $.get("getUser.php", {q:str}, function(data){

        //data holds what getUser.php echoes
        $("#yourTable").replaceWith(data);

    });

});
```

Comment: David, first thank you for your help. Have to learn much, I know that. 
To answer your questions above: 
str: I thought I get it from the click/function on the cell. In replacewith-examples I clicked on a cell and were able to replace the original with "this".
As for the str: In an example I used for the code there was a form with a dropdown list. There options have given the value for str.
Maybe I should take a nap and get a clear head. This is the main problem.

Comment: Maybe I approach wrong. I want to use this as follow:
in a table 1 I have a list, e.g. car makers with short symbol, name, number of car models. I want to click on the short symbol, e.g. GM for General Motors. This should be the string and this I would like to use in Ajax + mySQL to load every car model produced by the car maker.
But, as you mentioned, I already have a problem with getting the string. Read many articles but either I don't understand or it is totally different. 
David, do you eventually have an idea? It is frustrating.