# Let a div get a value from a fetch-array-table row after click on a cell with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

first I want to say that this question is related to [jquery replacewith to get data with Ajax after click on a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159854/jquery-replacewith-to-get-data-with-ajax-after-click-on-a-cell/22160048?noredirect=1#22160048) and if this against the rule I am sorry and delete this post.

I tried to get the value of a cell in a MySQL-generated table (with fetch_array). I want to click on a cell in the same and receive the value of the first cell in the row in a div-container.

Thanks to several entries here I found an example for "static" tables. Like this:

```
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
      <th>Name/Nr.</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Town</th>
      <th>Postcode</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr"><span>50</span>

      </td>
      <td>Some Street 1</td>
      <td>Glasgow</td>
      <td>G0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td class="use-address">
        Use
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="chip" class="nr">49</td>
      <td>Some Street 2</td>
      <td>Glasgow</td>
      <td>G0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
          <button type="button" class="use-address">Use</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<div id="glasgow">Hello</div>
```

and

```
$("#chip").click(function () {
  var scotland = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();
   
  $("#glasgow").html(scotland);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FnDvL/231/

Works fine. I insert this to my file, php, and get table data from mysql.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".information").click(function () {
  var rodney = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();
   
  $(".clicked_info").html(rodney);
});
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','boerse');
$sql="SELECT short, name FROM markets";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
 



    <div class="markets">

<?
echo "<table>
<thead border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody border='1'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='nr'>" . $row['short'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='information'>Use</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
<div class="clicked_info">Hello</div>  
    </div>
<br><br>

            
</body>
</html>
```

Now my problem is that I can click on the td with class information, but div class 'clicked_info' doesn't change. But I did like in the fiddle. So what went wrong? Or where is the problem? It must have to do with the MySQL-matter. But why?

This way I want to check if I got the content from the cell and I can continue working with it (as seen in my post before).

Maybe anyone can help. And again I am sorry if I break rules here.

Thank you to everyone.

Comment: Wrap your event handler `$(".information").click(function () {.....` in document-ready handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in [**document-ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".information").click(function () {
        var rodney = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();
        $(".clicked_info").html(rodney);
    });
});
```

Currently when your script executes there is no `$(".information")` thus event is not binded properly.

*OR*

Move your script at the bottom of your page. like

```
<script>
$(".information").click(function () {
  var rodney = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();

  $(".clicked_info").html(rodney);
});
</script>
</body>
```

*OR*

You can use event-delegation

```
$(document).on("click", ".information",function () {
  var rodney = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();

  $(".clicked_info").html(rodney);
});
```

Comment: can you eventually help on the topic I linked to at the beginning of the topic?

Comment: Right. Your help yesterday helped very much and I today added the changed code.

Comment: @user3088932, I will try let us switch to that question

Comment: Am on the question page.